# Bluetooth LE getting the protocol of a product

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

We have a hardware product (toy) that we use to buy from a supplier, that is controlled by an iPhone app, with the `bluetooth LE` protocol. We are having hard time to understand their protocol documents (China), and we would like to write our own app to control the product.

Does setting it to be `peripheral`, and the iPhone to be `Central`, and writing some demo app is possible to start "talking" with it? or do we need to actually knowing all their `words` in the protocol?
We are looking for some tool (some snipper?) to know how can we control it.

Comment: If you don't know how it works and what « language » is spoken, you won't do anything. Protocols and doc are there for a reason.

Comment: got it, so i must have the document for the protocol as i thought..what do you mean by language? do you set a language in the bluetooth 4.0?  the people in China say its a big secret.. :) so hard to work like that.

Comment: No. BLE works with Services & Characteristics. But, what to put in a specific characteristic? An int? A string? A custom struct? etc. It would be all reverse engeenering.

Comment: I think you can listen in on BLE traffic with a CC2540 USB Dongle and the SmartRF Packet Sniffer from TI.